# add textarea content with jquery using php variable

Tags: php, jquery, variables, insert, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (including escaping newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)

Hy, so my problem is that i have a textarea which is generated with jquery, like this:

```
$var input = $('<textarea name="somename"></textarea>');
$(something).after(input);
```

But i also want to fill this textarea with content (when content exists of course), using php. sp now my code looks like this:

```
$var input = $('<textarea name="somename"><?=$variabel[0][something];?</textarea>');
$(something).after(input);
```

So the problem with this is that when i run this code the javascript automatically fills the content of the textarea in that input variable, and because there is more than one line it breaks so i get an error saying "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

I hope i explained it well, so i need somehow the put the content of the textarea inside that generated textarea, but in a way in which my input doesn't break.

Thans for any advice!

Comment: Try to remove `$` before `var`s, and add `>` after `;?`.

Comment: @Engineer sorry i misspelled, but in my real code it's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the php function json_encode() to encode your PHP variable before it is output. It will convert newlines to \n, for example. More details about the function can be found here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

In your case it would be something like this:

```
var input = '<textarea name="somename"><?= json_encode($variabel[0][something]); ?></textarea>';
```

Also refer to the following question: [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines/169035#169035)

Comment: No problem. Also I think `json_encode()` is a better alternative to `htmlentities()` as it was made specifically for javascript

Answer (score 0):

remove the `$` it's not a php variable, try this:

```
var input = $('<textarea name="somename"></textarea>');
$(something).after(input);
$('textarea[name="somename"]').val( <?php echo $variabel[0]['something']; ?> )
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var $input = $('<?php echo "<textarea name=\"somename\">".htmlentities($variable[0]['something'])."</textarea>" ?>');
```

Comment: Who's downvoting all of the answers here without leaving a comment?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is a syntax error, you needed a `>` to close your PHP tag:

```
$var input = $('<textarea name="somename"><?=$var;?></textarea>');
```

This error can be easily detected by using a console, which is built into Chrome. Or if you use Firefox you can an extention called [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/).